# In PostGreSQL should the back references of a regexp_replace work in a CASE statement?

Tags: regex, postgresql, switch-statement

Example (the ELSE always gets chosen):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABCDEFG','(C)(D)', CASE WHEN '\1' = 'C' THEN '+\2\1+' ELSE '-\1\2-' END);
**returns =>** AB-CD-EFG

SELECT regexp_replace('ABCDEFG','(C)(D)', CASE '\1' WHEN 'C' THEN '+\2\1+' ELSE '-\1\2-' END);
**returns =>** AB-CD-EFG
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: It seems the '\1' in the WHEN is a literal  and not a back-reference but the result in the THEN can contain back-references.  I am using PostGres 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't.

I would use `regexp_match` with groups for the stuff before C and after D as well, and then construct the result from the matched parts using CASE and concatenation.